# Is it possible to have a response form or text field in Mailchimp or emails in general?

Tags: email, mailchimp

I know it's possible to have a polling survey in Mailchimp, but can we have a text field where people can submit responses as well, inline within the email, without being sent to a landing page?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to code the email yourself, you would probably be able to include an input field. The thing is though, it won't work. Input fields are part of forms, and forms need a location to submit the entered data to. Email clients don't support that kind of data transfers, ergo: nope, not possible!

Final thought: if using a landing page isn't an option, you can always create an email link that simply allows your recipients to reply to the email with their answer to your question. Might not be the most elegant solution, but in some situations it does the trick just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the response! That's more or less what I suspected, but our clients seemed to refuse to believe it was not possible, so just wanted to check here.

Comment: No worries - always happy to help battle sceptical clients. ;-)